# dplyr function throws "Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : invalid argument to unary operator"

Tags: r, dplyr

Long time SAS user but newbie R programmer trying to learn through Coursera's R Programming course. On the final assignment, trying to output the lowest mortality rate of a hospital, with function inputs of state and outcome name (e.g., heart attack).

I'm trying to do everything with dplyr since I know it's a great way to wrangle data. But my code below throws an "Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : invalid argument to unary operator" error.

Here's what I've tried: reviewed the "R for Data Science" book, searched StackOverflow and other online places, ran snippets of my function to narrow down where it is (I've only pasted a snippet of my function since the error occurs in 3 places), shown traceback, etc. Of course, I've tried a lot of different edits to the code after all these sources but nada.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

```
best <- function(state_input, oc_name) {
    outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")    
    if (oc_name == "heart attack") {
        return_outcome <- outcome %>% select(State, 
                                         Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack) %>% 
            filter(State == state_input) %>% 
            arrange(Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack) %>%
            top_n(1, -Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack)
    }
}
best(state_input = "TX", oc_name = "heart attack")
```

Comment: as your specified  `colClasses = "character"`, all columns would be character. Thus `- Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack` would through an error. If you want to avoid some characters columns being read as numeric, make sure to convert other columns to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably associated with what mt1022 said about the character column class argument. Instead you should use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`:

```
outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You might want to also consider loading your data outside the function call and removing the conditional statement, unless you are planning to have different sections to handle other types of outcomes with the same function:

```
best_heart_attack <- function(state_input, outcome) {
    return_outcome <- outcome %>% 
        select(State, Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack) %>% 
        filter(State == state_input) %>% 
        arrange(Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack) %>%
        top_n(1, -Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack)

    return(return_outcome)
}

best_heart_attack(state_input = "TX", outcome = outcome)
```